# /users/self & /users/{id} route in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, restful-url

I currently have users routes using ModelViewSet for CRUD operations.

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

However, I would like to have endpoints similar to Instagram users: https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/

- /users/{user-id}
- /users/self

both having the same CRUD ops, except one is to use request.user (if logged in).

How would I go about doing this?  Using ModelViewSet and SimpleRouter?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Its better to use different viewsets for

```
/users/{user-id} - PublicProfileViewset
/users/self - MyProfileViewSet
```

The reason is both viewset deals with different permissions and different queryset. For e.g PublicProfileViewset can be accessed by anyone without login. But MyprofileViewset should be accessed only by logged in user. Its similar to public profile and your own profile of github.

For `PublicProfileViewset,` you can simple use router. unfortunately, I don't know how to user simple routers for `MyProfileViewset` as here user object is taken from `request` object itself like `request.user`

views.py

```
class PublicUserProfileViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    """
    Public end-points to get information about any user
    NOTE: All end-points provided here is read-only
    """

    queryset = User.objects.public()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
    lookup_field = 'user_id'
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'pk'

class MyProfileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    End-points to get all details about logged in user
    and update the profile of logged in user
    """
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

urls.py

```
router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'users', PublicProfileViewSet)

urlpatterns = router.urls

urlpatterns += [
    url(r'^users/me/$', MyProfileViewSet.as_view(
        {'get': 'retrieve', 'put': 'update', 'patch': 'partial_update', 'delete': 'delete'}),
        name='myprofile'),
]
```